# Overloaded operator, but still "no match for operator" error

Tags: c++

I have a class that overloads the output operator "<<", and I have implemented it as such. However, the compiled complains about "no match for operator <<.." in the main method. I have no idea why it's not working.

```
/*
 * Accumulator.cpp
 *
 *  
 *      
 */
#include <iostream>
#include "Accumulator.h"

using namespace std;


Accumulator::~Accumulator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void Accumulator::operator+=(const int nbr) {
    nbrs.push_back(nbr);
}

void Accumulator::undo() {
    if (!comitted) {
        nbrs.pop_back();
    }
}

void Accumulator::commit() {
    lastCommit = nbrs;
    comitted = true;
}

void Accumulator::rollback() {
    nbrs = lastCommit;
}

ostream& Accumulator::operator<<(ostream &out, const Accumulator &accum){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int nbr : nbrs){
        sum+= nbr;
    }
    out << sum;
    return out;
}
int main() {
    Accumulator accum;
    char cmd;
    while (cin >> cmd) {
        switch (cmd) {
        case 'p':
        cout << "Sum is now " << accum << endl;
        break;
        case 'a': {
            int nbr;
            cin >> nbr;
            accum += nbr;
            break;
        }
        case 'u':
        accum.undo();
        break;
        case 'c':
        accum.commit();
        break;
        case 'r':
        accum.rollback();
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: for **member** operator<<, parameters are different. You need only right hand argument.

Comment: Don't make it a member function.

Comment: For a binary member operator, the left-hand side is `*this` and the right-hand side is the parameter (there can only be one). You can't overload the stream operator as a member.

Comment: I'm confused. How do I overload it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-static member functions always have an extra *hidden* parameter, which is the `this` pointer, the object on which the function is called. So lets say you have a class like this:

```
class Test {
    public:
        void f(int param) {
        }
};

Test t;
t.f(10);
```

The call `t.f(10)` is basically equivalent to something like this in the background: `Test::f(&t, 10)` (note that this is not valid code, it's just to give you an idea of what happens).

Now going back to your operator, if you make it a member function in your class, then you can't call it as you normally would. That is because calling it like this:

```
std::cout << accum;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
cout.operator<<(accum);
```

which in the background is equivalent to this:

```
Accumulator::operator<<(&cout, accum);
```

while your member function is equivalent to this:

```
ostream& operator<<(Accumulator* this, ostream &out, const Accumulator &accum);
```

Notice that the parameters don't match.

So the only way to correctly overload `operator<<` is to make it a free function:

```
class Accumulator {...};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Accumulator &accum);
```

This way, a normal call like this:

```
std::cout << accum;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
operator<<(std::cout, accum);
```

which matches exactly the declaration of the overload.

If in your overload implementation you need to access private members of your `Accumulator` class, you can do it in different ways: make your overload a friend of the class for example, or add a public function in your class like this:

```
class Accumulator {
public:
    void printToStream(ostream &out) const {
        out << private_members;
    }
};
```

and call it from your operator overload like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Accumulator &accum) {
    accum.printToStream(out);
    return out;
}
```

Now you don't have to make the overload a friend of the class anymore.

Comment: Interesting. I was not aware of the concept of "free functions", and it's a bit strange to me. Nevertheless your post was very informative and I'm always excited about learning how things like this actually works than just the "this is how to do it" kind of answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @n.m. , the stream injectors must not be overloaded as member function but as 2 parameters plain functions.

Your .h file becomes:

```
class Accumulator {
   ... // no operator << here !
};

ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Accumulator& accum);
```

and implementation:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Accumulator& accum) {
    ...
    return out;
}
```

You would only use the one parameter member function overload, if you were writing a custom `ostream` class (say a specialized logger for example).